# Can't control bluetooth in Saucy

Tags: bluetooth

I can't get bluetooth on my laptop to work properly in Ubuntu 13.10.

- There is no bluetooth indicator visible, but `indicator-bluetooth` is installed
- The bluetooth control panel is greyed out, with the "power switch" for bluetooth in the "off" position. When I change it to "on" nothing happens. There is nothing in syslog.
- `service bluetooth status` reports that the service is running
- `hcitool dev` lists `hci0`
- `hciconfig` shows that `hci0` is "UP RUNNING"
- `hcitool scan` lists bluetooth devices when they're visible

`lsmod` shows two bluetooth modules:

```
$ lsmod | grep blue
bluetooth             372041  12 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
toshiba_bluetooth      12852  0
```

So, it looks like the hardware is detected, powered, and working. But none of the graphical utilities to control bluetooth are. What do I need to do so the normal bluetooth software works properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that removing then re-adding the `btusb` kernel module, then using `rfkill unblock bluetooth` will bring Bluetooth up. This causes the Bluetooth section of the control panel to start working again, as well as indicator-bluetooth to appear.

If I turn off Bluetooth with either of these, indicator-bluetooth disappears, and neither will work to turn Bluetooth back on again.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can use blueman, a nice graphical tool to control your bluetooth device.

you can install it from the command line:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install blueman
```

Comment: note that even `blueman` does not work in certain cases.

Comment: The normal stuff in the base install should work properly though, and it doesn't. Neither does `blueman`.